# SSIS File transfer task , Copy Files works but Move file property fails the task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, filesystems, flat-file

SSIS File System Task can copy but can't move the flat files?. I am trying to move the flat files from source to target folder but FST only working for copy. and while moving it throes and error saying that, file is being used by another process. I have tried using delay's also it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, File System Task can perform Move operations as mentioned in the link below, but make sure the the flat file is not used in a Flat File Connection Manager since it will lock the file for reading or writing and it will prevent the FST to perfrom a move operation.

**External Links**

- [Move File Using File System Task in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/move-file-using-file-system-task-in-ssis/)
- [Move Directory Using File System Task in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/move-directory-using-file-system-task-in-ssis/)